# Redirection on Elastic Load Balance based routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I need help in this scenario

- My an ec2 instance is receiving requests, I don't want on client end to change server path based on few requests (especially on chat)
- My first ec2 instance bypass requests based on few path patterns to my other created instance. (In other words, I want to redirect traffic from first to second)

Is there any way to fulfill above scenario.

Comment: I suppose you want to attach only the 1st ec2 instance to the ELB, and proxy requests to the other instance. If so, you could configure nginx on the 1st instance as a reverse proxy for the other through the private network, behind the ELB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as a proxy for your use case where you can plugin the two EC2 instances behind CloudFront as Origins and Add behavior rules (Path rules) to switch traffic to one or the other.

Your client will send requests only to the CloudFront URL(Or DNS mapped through Route53) and won't be knowing about the EC2 instances behind. This approach will work, if your EC2 instances are publicly accessible but will be cost effective and reduce the load on your services, if you happen to cache content.

Alternative approach is to use an [Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) with [path based routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules) configuration.

Following tutorial will guide you through the steps.

- Tutorial: [Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html)

Comment: is Classic Load Balancer can be used for above scenario?

Comment: No. Path based routing is Application Layer functionality which will require Application load balancer